# How to get the last callback in a function with several callbacks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have a `showMain()` function with a lot of jQuery [`.show("slow", callback)`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) methods, and each of these callbacks are triggered only when the corresponding slow "animation" is complete. How to write a `showMain(callback)` function, whose callback will be triggered only *once* and after *all* animations are complete?

Theoretically, imagine I have this set of functions

```js
function foo1(callback){
  //do something
  callback();
}

function foo2(callback){
  //do something
  callback();
}

function foo(callback){
  foo1(callback);
  foo2(callback);
}

foo(function(){
  alert("Hello");
});
```

How to write a function that will call its callback only *once*, and the *last* of them to be executed?

If I write this, the callback will be triggered twice.

Comment: I was investigating and I doubt it has to do with jQuery .promise(), I suppose

Comment: so after all the callbacks for `show` executed you want to trigger some other function? do you have a count on how many time you are calling `show` wit a callback in second arg?

Comment: jQuery animations chain in their animation queue, after you called all the methods just schedule another callback and it will be called in the end.

Comment: @Bergi but I don't want to chain them, I want them asynchronously.

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee, I don't have a count, because I don't have access to those functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about maintaining a counter if you know how many times you are calling show,

```
var callback = function() {....} // the function you want to execute when all done
var itemsToShow = 4; // just an example
var slowCallback = function(){
    itemsToShow--;
    if(itemsToShow===0) {
        callback();
    }
};
$(...).show('slow', slowCallback);
$(...).show('slow', slowCallback);
$(...).show('slow', slowCallback);
$(...).show('slow', slowCallback);
```

**Note**: It will work only if you know How many times you will call `.show` otherwise initialize the counter to `0` and increment with each `show` call

Answer (score 1):

if you want to work with callbacks then you will need a control var. I would solve your problem doing something like:

```
var i = 2 // number of your "shows" methods.
function foo1(callback){
  //do something
  x = x-1;
  if(x<=0)callback();
}

function foo2(callback){
  //do something
  x = x-1;
  if(x<=0)callback();
}

function foo(callback){
  foo1(callback);
  foo2(callback);
}
```

Your maybe you consider using `Promises` and `Promises.all` should solve your problem too.

Comment: Thanks, though I don't have access neither to `foo1()` nor `foo2()`

Answer (score 1):

You could bypass the control variable issue by converting them to Promises. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kqso0kkb/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.clear();

  Promise.all([one(), two()]).then(() => {
    console.log('all done');
  })

  function one() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $('#div').show("slow", resolve);
    }).then(() => console.log('done 1'));
  }

  function two() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $('#div').show("slow", resolve);
    }).then(() => console.log('done 2'));
  }
});
```

Instead of `console.log` you can put whatever callback you like. This way you can load up an array of any size with promises, and .all will take care of executing your function when they’re all finished

Comment: Thanks, though I don't have access to either `one()` nor `two()`

Comment: Much easier: `return Promise.resolve($('#div').show("slow").promise())`

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, that's more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I solved the issue:

```js
function foo(callback){
  
  $("#div1").show("slow");
  $("#div2").show("fast");
  
  if (typeof callback === 'function'){
    $("#div1, #div2").promise().done(callback);
  }
}
```

```css
#div1, #div2{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1">
 Text1
</div>
<div id="div2">
 Text2
</div>

<input type="button" value="show" onClick="foo(function(){alert('Show Once')})" />
```

Comment: When working with promises, better always `return` the promise instead of taking an (optional) callback. You'd then call it as `foo().then(function(){alert(…);});`